# Firebase Database returns null every time while reading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a class to read data from my database but it always returns `null`.

Here's the java file

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private String userID;


    private String TAG = "hifiwi";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Signed in with " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Successfully signed out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    }

    private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
            uInfo.setEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getEmail());
            uInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getName());
            uInfo.setPassword(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getPassword());
            uInfo.setPhoneno(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getPhoneno());

            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getEmail());    //Always returning null
            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getName());    //Always returning null
            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getPassword());    //Always returning null
            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getPhoneno());    //Always returning null

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

The log statements always return **null**.

This is my database structure under `t2-login`(the project name).

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "8dQ8unnqQXa69nkxUFKrcgiTM3S2" : {
      "emailuser" : "sam@gmail.com",
      "mobileUser" : "1234567899",
      "nameuser" : "sam",
      "passworduser" : "sammypp"
    },
    "DIMBAk4CHZdWGbxN9kPESwIrw9b2" : {
      "emailuser" : "hsjsjsjjsjsj@mdm.mdmdmdmndn",
      "mobileUser" : "9999999999",
      "nameuser" : "hshs",
      "passworduser" : "ppppppl"
    },
    "YJhf16ZyfWUn1Dou3BPcIkSSmVm1" : {
      "emailuser" : "test2@gmail.com",
      "mobileUser" : "1234567892",
      "nameuser" : "test2",
      "passworduser" : "test2pp"
    },
    "yQEFEe5x06hvSZP18Mmb6OfNqnB2" : {
      "emailuser" : "test1@gmail.com",
      "mobileUser" : "1234567891",
      "nameuser" : "test1",
      "passworduser" : "test1pp"
    }
  }
}
```

The UserInformation.class

```
package com.rishav.t2;

/**
 * Created by rishav on 6/27/2017.
 */

public class UserInformation {
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String phoneno;
    private String password;

    public UserInformation() {
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I know this that Your loops are not iterating over the keys individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set myRef to: `myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(user.getUid());`

Also change this:

```
  private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            UserInformation uInfo = ds.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getEmail());    //Always returning null
            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getName());    //Always returning null
            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getPassword());    //Always returning null
            Log.i(TAG, " " + uInfo.getPhoneno());    //Always returning null


    }
```

Have UserInformation class variables match the key names that exist in the firebase database:

```
public class UserInformation {
public String emailuser;
public String nameuser;
public String mobileUser;
public String passworduser;

public UserInformation() {
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhoneno() {
    return phoneno;
}

public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
    this.phoneno = phoneno;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Comment: @Rishav Did you authenticate the user?

Comment: The error is coming from getting the values from query

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Doing this does stop the app from crashing but it again returns null

Comment: Can you add your UserInformation class to the question?

Comment: Sure thing. Done.

Comment: Okay This finally worked but the phone number is still returning null

Comment: The issue might be in the capitalization of the 'u' in mobileUser. Make sure that they are identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147677/discussion-between-rishav-and-smedleydslap).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
     myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                //List<User> list= new ArrayList<User>(); 
                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = childDataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    userList.add(user);
                } 
                Log.e("hello","childDataSnapshot"+ userList.size());

                adapter.update(userList); 

            } 

            @Override 
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value 
                Log.w("MY", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            } 
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you want me to take `database.getReference("users")`  and not just `database.getReference()`

Comment: Cant resolve symbol 'adapter'..  n sorry im kind of new

Comment: Thats just my adapter for recycler view ... you can remove that line ... I am just showing all the users recently joined in a list

Comment: @Sankalp : Whats the issue you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the rule of your firebase project setting

Firebase rules provides a way to identify user role while performing read and write operations. These rules will acts a security layer on the server before perform any CRUD operation. By default the rules allows user to perform read & write operation only after authentication.

```
The below rules allow authenticated users only to read or write data.
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Below rules allows everyone to read & write data without authentication.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

You can also use these rules to validate data before inserting into database. For example below rules validates the name to be less than 50 chars and email to be valid using email regular expression.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "users": {
            "$user": {
                "name": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 50"
                },
                "email": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For detailed tutorial check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/)

Comment: Ya my rules are True for all. N i am logged in though.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  myRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Yet another wonderful way. if u add `myRef.child("Users").child(userID).....` to it