# Retrieve all Children from Firebase ChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have my firebase data structure shown below: 
[image: my_database_structure]

I want to retrieve all the children nodes of the root ( news_db ) and their respective values such as newsTitle, Url, etc and show them as a list in my recyclerview.

I have tried doing this with ValueEventListeners but getting null values in logcat. This is my code for retrieving data:

```
newsRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot articlesSnapShot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if (articlesSnapShot.getValue() != null){

                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) articlesSnapShot.getValue();
                String authorFromDB = hashMap.get(0);
                Log.i(TAG, "Title Rcvd is: \t" + authorFromDB);
                String titleFromDB = hashMap.get(0);
                String descFromDB = hashMap.get(0);
                String urlFromDB = hashMap.get(0);
                String urlToImageFromDB = hashMap.get(0);
                String pubAtFromDB = hashMap.get(0);

                NewsItem newsItem = new NewsItem(authorFromDB, titleFromDB, descFromDB, urlFromDB, urlToImageFromDB, pubAtFromDB);
                itemList.add(newsItem);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), itemList);
progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Could someone kindly guide me here? Thanks.

Comment: You can check my answer at this so post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772906/firebase-database-returns-null-every-time-while-reading/44772938#44772938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve those values, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference newsRef = rootRef.child("news_db");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String newsAuthor = ds.child("newsAuthor").getValue(String.class);
            String newsDate = ds.child("newsDate").getValue(String.class);
            String newsDesc = ds.child("newsDesc").getValue(String.class);
            String newsImageUrl = ds.child("newsImageUrl").getValue(String.class);
            String newsTitle = ds.child("newsTitle").getValue(String.class);
            String newsUrl = ds.child("newsUrl").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", newsAuthor + " / " + newsDate + " / " + newsDesc + " / " + newsImageUrl + " / " + newsTitle + " / " + newsUrl);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
newsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks. In my log cat, I can see the results are retrieved properly. How can I update the UI by showing all the items in separate cards in the recyclerview?

Comment: I get this exception in logcat, java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to in.co.tings.josephjoey.tings.model.NewsItem. Can you send me your email so I can forward you the code to review. Appreciate the efforts.

Comment: I wrote the above code assuming that the `news_db` is a direct child of your firebase database. Can please share us your database structure? The only thing that can be wrong is the `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: My database structure is at the top of this page. Meanwhile, check the link to my class code here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6HfIWuQkLSiemFLOTJQaWpFVjg. Please help me point out the changes I should make. Thanks

Comment: You shared only a piece of your database, not the entire tree including your root, which is need to identify the correct `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153277/discussion-between-anand-rajput-and-alex-mamo).